# php pdo mysql wont return text with quotes

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Okay so for my app I use php's pdo with mysql, i have this in the database:

```
"Tiny & Big: Grandpa's Leftovers" - 75% off
```

Now for some reason have the quotes in it won't let me echo it out to a form field for editing, it works fine for any entries that don't have quotes.

Now i've checked my queries output and it clearly gives me the option:

```
[info] => "Tiny & Big: Grandpa's Leftovers" - 75% off
```

So I am wandering why it can't use it?

I fetch data using this small function:

```
    public function fetch()
{
    $this->STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    return $this->STH->fetch();
}
```

And the actual query function:

```
    // the main sql query function
public function sqlquery($sql, $objects = array())
{
    global $core;

    try
    {
        $this->STH = $this->database->prepare($sql);

        foreach($objects as $k=>$p)
        {
            // +1 is needed as arrays start at 0 where as ? placeholders start at 1 in PDO
            if(is_numeric($p))
            {
                $this->STH->bindValue($k+1, (int)$p, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->STH->bindValue($k+1, $p, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
        }

        return $this->STH->execute();
    }

    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $core->message($e->getMessage());
    }

    $this->counter++;

    $this->queries .= "<br />$sql";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Form fields for editing" is a tip to me that you're doing something like:

```
<input value="<?php echo $row['info']; ?>">
```

That won't work very well because of the quote in the `info` field.  It outputs `value=""`.  Use `htmlspecialchars($row['info'], ENT_QUOTES)` to properly escape the quotes for emission in the html.

Comment: Hmm should i then be doing that for all time i am putting database output into a text field?

Comment: That fixed it! So thank you for that, I will use entities since sometimes users may put double, sometimes single.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `htmlspecialchars` will convert both with `ENT_QUOTES` set.